# NameError: global name is not defined help required

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python making a nice little encryption program. Takes 3 numbers and spits them out + 7 to each digit and swaps the first and last digit. At the bottom it wont print my encrypted variable. NameError: global name 'encrypted' is not defined... but it is?

```
def main():
    global unencrypted, encrypted
    unencrypted = int (input("Enter a 3-digit number: "))

    def isolate_digits():                 # separate the 3 digits into variables
        global units, tenths, hundreths
        units = unencrypted % 10
        tenths = (unencrypted / 10) % 10
        hundreths = (unencrypted / 100) % 10

    def replace_digits():                 # perform the encryption on each digit
        global encrypted_unit, encrypted_tenths, encrypted_hendreths
        encrypted_unit = ((units + 7) % 10)
        encrypted_tenths = ((tenths + 7) % 10)
        encrypted_hendreths = ((hundreths + 7) %10)

    def swap_digit_1_with_digit_3():
        temp = encrypted_unit
        encrypted_unit = encrypted_hundreths
        encrypted_hundreths = temp

    def recompose_encrypted_number():     # create the encrypted variable
        global encrypted
        encrypted = encrypted_unit * 1 + encrypted_tenths * 10 + encrypted_hundreths * 100

    print("Unencrypted: ", unencrypted)
    print("Encrypted:   ", encrypted)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Functions don't do anything unless you call them.
2. You are missing `global` declarations in `swap_digit_1_with_digit_3`.
3. You spelled `encrypted_hundreths` in two different ways.

```
def main():
    global unencrypted, encrypted
    unencrypted = int (input("Enter a 3-digit number: "))

    def isolate_digits():                 # separate the 3 digits into variables
        global units, tenths, hundreths
        units = unencrypted % 10
        tenths = (unencrypted / 10) % 10
        hundreths = (unencrypted / 100) % 10

    def replace_digits():                 # perform the encryption on each digit
        global encrypted_unit, encrypted_tenths, encrypted_hundreths
        encrypted_unit = ((units + 7) % 10)
        encrypted_tenths = ((tenths + 7) % 10)
        encrypted_hundreths = ((hundreths + 7) %10)

    def swap_digit_1_with_digit_3():
        global encrypted_unit, encrypted_hundreths
        temp = encrypted_unit
        encrypted_unit = encrypted_hundreths
        encrypted_hundreths = temp

    def recompose_encrypted_number():     # create the encrypted variable
        global encrypted
        encrypted = encrypted_unit * 1 + encrypted_tenths * 10 + encrypted_hundreths * 100

    isolate_digits()
    replace_digits()
    swap_digit_1_with_digit_3()
    recompose_encrypted_number()
    print("Unencrypted: ", unencrypted)
    print("Encrypted:   ", encrypted)

main()
```

Result:

```
Enter a 3-digit number: 123
Unencrypted:  123
Encrypted:    101.23
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply, what a simple mistake to make.  The other problem i'm having is it's supposed to output + 7 to each of the first digits,  then swap the first number with the last.

For example 111 would become 888
Or 314 would become 180 (10)8(11)

Its just giving me random float numbers

Comment: Oh, in that case you need integer division in `isolate_digits`. Replace each `/` with `//`. This will cause the result to be a whole number instead of a float.

Comment: Im not using a / in isolate_digits, where does it go?

Comment: it's strange I input 111 and the output is 24, it should be 888

Comment: Could be a transcription error somewhere. [Here](http://ideone.com/S2mJsS) is a demo that does produce 888.

Comment: Thanks Kevin you've been a huge help, one final question.  If you input 003 it should display 077 but shows 77.  What format do you use so it includes leading zeros

Comment: You could use the `.format` method: `print("Encrypted: {:03}".format(encrypted))`